# How to use SSR or SSG in components in a single page to load API data dynamically after a fixed duration of time?

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to make an application using NEXT JS where I will have to display multiple components inside a single page, and each component will call a different API, after a distinct and fixed period of time.

[image]

For example, In the picture above, "A" component should call A-API after every 6 hours and build a page on the server, and serve it until the 6 hours are passed. "B" calls B-API every second, as the data changes in real time and so on.

My problem is, I'm not able to use Static Generation (for data that does not change frequently) or Server Side Rendering (for volatile components) nested inside a single page.

How can we archive the Delayed API calls & Different types of generations clubbed under a single page? Can the delayed API calls for certain components be achieved by third party libs such as SWR?

Comment: _"build a page on the server, and serve it until the 6 hours are passed"_ - Why do you need the page to be built on the server after an interval of time has passed? Why not just make the revalidation requests from the client, and client-side render the page instead? You can still generate the full page upfront on the server for the initial page load, which is when SSR matters.

Comment: I can go ahead and make revalidation requests from the client, I am trying ISR for a few components and Client side generation for a few. I didn't want to client-side render the page because the API resources are limited (5 calls/day) and throwing a call every time the client access the page will be waste of resources.

Comment: _"the API resources are limited (5 calls/day)"_ - Is that for the A-API only? As you're making requests to B-API every second, I assume it doesn't have that restriction. I guess using ISR with revalidation every 6 hours for the A-API data, and then doing client-side revalidation for B-API data could potentially work.

Comment: Yes, the limitations are for A-API only, and thanks for the suggestion I am implementing it in this way. But the only issue I was facing is the fact that on the first request after the revalidation period has ended (ISR), It will still show the stale version of the page (But will build a page in the back with the new data, which will show in the next request). So I would have to ask the user to refresh or do it with JS myself or something.